# SwitchMap has no effect on custom subject?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

[jsfiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/6pz981gd/453/)
Code:

```
const source = new Rx.Subject()
source.switchMap(x => {
    console.log(x)
  return Rx.Observable()
})

source.next('hello')
```

I expected that 'hello' would be logged, but nothing happened. Can't I use switchMap on custom subject?

Comment: In his answer, Martin has called `subscribe`. You didn't call it and that was your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the value (Observable emitting the value):

```
const source = new Rx.Subject()
source
  .switchMap(x => {
    console.log(x)
    return Rx.Observable.of(x);
  })
  .subscribe(...)

source.next('hello')
```

Comment: 'hello' is not logged. You have misunderstood my question.